# mysql where clause in not return empty?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello This is my table.

**table name is  location**

```
id      location
1       location1
2       location2
3       location3
4       location2
5       location4
6       location3
```

the below are query.

```
SELECT * FROM location WHERE `location` IN ('location2,location1')
```

it return empty value i need output to all location1 and location2 records in table

**i need output is**

```
1    location1
2    location2
4    location2
```

thank you.

Comment: try ('location2','location1')

Comment: @Strawberry ok sorry that is my mistake. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM location WHERE `location` IN ('location2' ,'location1') LIMIT 20
```

Your error was in the quotes containing the possible values.